# Removed tiles... what's underneath and how to proceed?

Tags: bathroom, drywall, tile

I've removed a couple of tiles from my bathroom wall (for a remodel), and I'm unsure about what each of the layers are underneath, how to proceed, and how to make sure I'm not damaging anything structural.

I was expecting plasterboard and then bricks, but am not sure exactly what I'm looking at.

Below are photos, of the top corner.

[image: underneath removed tiles in bathroom]

[image: underneath removed tiles in bathroom]

[image: underneath removed tiles with soda can for scale]

Comment: Are we looking at a top corner?  Can you include a soda can or something for scale, please.

Comment: @ZachMierzejewski Yes, top corner, and added a photo with a can

Comment: That is plaster wall, old school.. How old is the house, built before 1950? You should find strips of wood under it all. I see the hair in it for strenghtening, and the gray top coat for the smooth finish. It is usually white though...

Comment: Then again it could be applied right over brick. How the answer goes will make a difference, but if you remove anymore, you will need to secure a cement board over the wall most likely to replace the dimension that is taken away by removing the plaster.

Comment: @jack Yes, pre 1950. Somewhere around 1900 (although converted to flats more recently).

Comment: Have you confirmed what is under the plaster yet?

Comment: @Jack No. What would I need to do to do this? (I fear damaging something structural or going through to the adjacent flat!)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33799/discussion-between-jack-and-michal-charemza).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like drywall over old plaster (horse hair plaster) that was applied to a brown coat which has horse hair in it. This might be real good because that brown coat could be over an inch deep & will take screws beautifully for a cement board covering & easy remodel.